# Adding an inheritance to an Qt designed object

Tags: c++, qt4

I have a problem and I want to implement the MVC pattern to my QT application, that's why I need for example to inherite in my QTableWidget about another class like

```
myClass
{
    myMethod();
}
```

but our QTableWidget is contained by our Mainwidows that is designed by the QT designer and generate an ui_MainWindow class !

Do you know how to do that ?

Is that a method inside the Qt Designer to do that ? or another method ?

Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use custom objects in QDesigner. Right click on the widget that you want to have as an instance of a something that is not available in designer and select "Promote to ...". In that dialog you can enter a custom class and a include file where the declaration for your class can be found.

BUT Qt implements uses MVC for a lot of the classes look at `QTableView` as opposed to `QTableWidget`, `QTableView` uses `QAbstractItemModel` as the model class and there is a pretty strict separation between the view and the model. See also [An Introduction to Model/View Programming @ Nokia](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/model-view-introduction.html)